# JSON - Framework on iPhone SDK error

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, frameworks

I'm getting an error when I run any project with the [JSON-Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) installed:

Xcode could not locate source file: NSString+SBJSON.m (line: 50)

I assumed this means it can't find the sdk, the strange this is that the project builds and runs up until I make my first JSON call:

```
NSArray *data = [responseString JSONValue];
```

The JSON folder is in:
~/Library/SDKs

I added the additional sdks argument: 
$HOME/Library/SDKs/JSON/$(PLATFORM_NAME).sdk

I also added the linker flags:
-ObjC -ljson

To make sure I wasn't crazy, I ran a tutorial [here](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/first-json-iphone-application/).  This tutorial also gets the same error. (I also ran one from mobile orchard with similar results, except for the file: SBJSON.m)

I must have set something up wrong, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your machines problem is because it sounds like you are doing everything right but remember that if you are releasing the app to the app store you'll need to embed the source into your project because it will not be approved if you are linking to custom frameworks

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I did just add the source anyways to get on with my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the above comments, I just added the source code directly. Not the ideal solution, but it worked.

I'm sure installation will get better...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get info on your file and make sure the path type is set to "Relative to Project".  This resolved my issue.